# Android: dynamically remove spinner items dependent to other spinners

Tags: android, spinner, android-arrayadapter

i have many spinners in my android application, initially all four spinner will loaded with default content. once the user select the item form any spinner the item should be removed from all other 3 spinner

i ll generate the spinners dynamically based on **preDefQuesCount**
i have arrayAdapter csAdapter.
this method is working but when i select  spinner multiple times the content is not removed properly same items are available all spinners. some other items are getting selected instead of what i select

**any idea what might have happened**

My code

```
   final Spinner sQuesArray[] = new Spinner[preDefQuesCount];

    for (int i = 0; i < preDefQuesCount; i++) {

        sQuesArray[i] = allQuestionSpinner.get(i);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < preDefQuesCount; i++) {
        sQuesArray[i]
                .setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0,
                            View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
                        final List<String> selectedText=new ArrayList<String>();
                        System.out.println("in between "+preDefQuesCount);
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                        for (int j = 0; j < preDefQuesCount; j++) {
                            System.out.println("item selected "
                                    + sQuesArray[j]
                                            .getSelectedItemPosition());
                            if (sQuesArray[j].getSelectedItemPosition() != 0) {
                                posstion[j] = sQuesArray[j]
                                        .getSelectedItemPosition();
                                selectedText.add(sQuesArray[j].getSelectedItem().toString());
                            }



                        }

                        List<String> temp = new ArrayList();


                            temp.addAll(a);
                            System.out.println("side "
                                    + preDefQuestions.size());

                            System.out.println("temp side " + temp.size());

                            for(int k=0;k<posstion.length;k++){
                                if(posstion[k]!=0){
                                temp.remove(posstion[k]);
                                }
                            }


                            for (int j = 0; j < preDefQuesCount; j++) {

                            csAdapter[j].clear();

                            csAdapter[j].addAll(new ArrayList(temp));

                            csAdapter[j].notifyDataSetChanged();





                            System.out.println(temp + " " + j);


                        }
                            temp.clear();

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    }

                });
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the [link](http://sunil-android.blogspot.in/2013/01/dynamic-change-content-of-spinner.html) which dynamically update the second spinner based on first one.

You can do like this by removing content from listview by selecting item from first spinner and notify the list.

Comment: Thanks sanket will it be possible to use single adapter for all spinner.

Comment: You cannot use single adapter because it will affect to your both spinner. So it is better to use two different adapters for two spinners.

Answer (score 0):

When the Spinner change put the data Inside the adapter of the next spinner . And the just write adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); The content Inside the next spinner will change.

```
spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int arg2, long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub


                string str=spinner1.getSelectedItem().toString();
                if(str.equals("spinner item"))//spinner item is selected item of spinner1
                {
                    ArrayAdapter<String>adapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, array1);

             spinner2.setAdapter(adapter1);//pass this updated adapter1 to second spinner
                }else if{
               ArrayAdapter<String>adapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, array2);

             spinner2.setAdapter(adapter2);

    }
        }
```